# Designing a randomly generated simple(nonintersecting) curves

Tags: java, recursion, path

I'm having some difficulty trying to randomly generate simple, i.e. they do not intersect, curves

Basically, the problem is that given a random assortment of points generated on the X,Y plane, how can you connect them in such a way to create a non intersecting curve. (i'm doing this in JAVA)

Right now, my only idea is to recursively start from the beginning and check for intersections with the Line2D class and then terminate the path if it intersects before trying the next point. Can anyone help?

Thanks for the help!

-edit-

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I still want to be able to generate curves that can take any variety of shape. For instance, having a curve shaped like a +/- sqrt function where the curve is can "curve" back in on itself

Comment: What do you do at the moment? And how should your curves look like? A single curve or more than one? Quite straight or any special properties?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Computation_of_convex_hulls) is one approach. Several [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) are available.

Comment: Does this basically generate a shape/curve that generally takes the form of a convex shape? Or can it also be a very messy shape, i.e. a triangular wave kind of thing?

Comment: There's a picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Intuitive_picture).

Comment: There's an interactive demonstration of Graham's Scan [here](http://yoshihitoyagi.com/projects/mesh/convexhull/grahamsscan/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Find the bottom right most point. that is the start. Then find the point who's line between the first point and that point is the smallest slope (closest to 0 degrees). Pick that one as the next point. continue doing that picking a new point with the smallest slope. Draw a curve through those points in that order.